# Same table, group by type max date, 2 rows difference

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, difference

How can I do this? I have this table

```
╔════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ item   ║ price    ║ date     ║
╠════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ Dollar ║       60 ║ 1.3.2016 ║
║ Dollar ║       50 ║ 2.3.2016 ║
║ Bound  ║      100 ║ 1.3.2016 ║
║ Bound  ║      110 ║ 2.3.2016 ║
║ Euro   ║      600 ║ 1.3.2016 ║
║ Euro   ║      580 ║ 3.3.2016 ║
╚════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Output should display one item from each type with last price dedepnding on last date and price difference from previous row, like this:

```
╔════════╦══════════╦════════════════════════╗
║ item   ║ price    ║ date     ║ differnece  ║
╠════════╬══════════╬════════════════════════╣
║ Dollar ║       50 ║ 2.3.2016 ║   -10       ║
║ Bound  ║      110 ║ 2.3.2016 ║    10       ║
║ Euro   ║      580 ║ 3.3.2016 ║   -20       ║
╚════════╩══════════╩════════════════════════╝
```

I did this...

---

```
SELECT item,date,price FROM wpdatatable_23 WHERE date IN (SELECT max(date) FROM wpdatatable_23 GROUP BY item LIMIT 0,1) group by item
```

...and it is working fine. I just don't know how to do the difference thing, any help?

Comment: Will there always only be two rows? If so, I'd consider changing your structure to be a single row.

Comment: Sorry. It should display all currencies in the table grouped by item

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the difference using a correlated subquery:

```sql
SELECT item, `date`, price,
       price - (SELECT price
                FROM wpdatatable_23 AS t2
                WHERE t2.item = t1.item AND t2.`date` < t1.date 
                ORDER BY t2.`date` DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS difference
FROM wpdatatable_23 AS t1 
WHERE date IN (SELECT max(date) 
               FROM wpdatatable_23 
               GROUP BY item )
```

Comment: Thank you, it kinda worked, but it repeated same items more than once.

Comment: @egaidi This is probably because you have records having the same max date value for the same item. Which one would you like to select in this case?

Comment: last date from each item

Comment: @egaidi Yes but you have *more than one* records having the *same last date* for *the same item*.

Comment: True, but I want to display only one result from each item, is that possible?

Comment: @egaidi You can use `group by item, date`

Answer (score 0):

Check this one (small modification of Giorgos SQL):

```
SELECT
    a.item,
    a.`date`,
    a.price,
    a.price  - (SELECT price
                FROM prices AS t2
                WHERE t2.item = a.item AND t2.`date` < a.`date` 
                ORDER BY t2.`date` DESC LIMIT 0,1) as diff
FROM
    prices AS a
WHERE
    a.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM prices b WHERE b.item = a.item GROUP BY item);
```